# Martingale problem for expectation and covariance

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I'm not looking for an explicit solution, but some suggestions.

> Let $(X_n)$ be a martingale adapted to $(\mathcal F_n)$ where, $\forall n,X_{n+1}X_n^{-1}\in L^1$. Show that $\mathbb E(X_{n+1}X_n^{-1})=1$ and $\mathrm{Cov}(X_{n+1}X_n^{-1},X_n X_{n-1}^{-1})=0$.

My thoughts so far: So $X_n$ is $\mathcal F_n$ measurable meaning that, coupled together with $X_{n+1}$ and $\mathcal F_{n+1}$, this is sort of "previsible". Since $X_n$ is both a martingale and "previsible", we have $X_n=X_0$ (almost everywhere). In particular, $\forall n,\mathbb E(X_{n+1}X_0^{-1})=\mathbb E(X_n X_0^{-1})$, and taking $n=0$ for the base case the RHS is just $1$ and I can induct on the relation to show that this is always $1$ for any $n$.

I'm like 90% sure this is wrong and I'm misunderstanding something, but I'm very lost at the moment as for an approach. A hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Law of total expectation might help you

Comment: How should I pick my partitions? $\mathcal F_{n+1}\setminus\mathcal F_n$? It's not clear to me what this gets.

Comment: $\mathbb{E} X_{n+1}/X_n  = \mathbb{E}\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}/X_n|\mathcal{F}_n] $ and now it's time to exploit some properties of conditional expectation and definition of martingale

Comment: Aha, I think that gets me the desired result almost immediately. Forgot that $1/X_n$ is $\mathcal F_n$-measurable.